# Is the "no database" option removed for Gateway Microservice in JHipster v5.3.1?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, microservices, jhipster

I once created a Gateway Microservice application without databases using OIDC. But now, I tried to upgrade my JHipster version to 5.3.1 and the option is no longer available.

Is the `no database` option removed for Gateway Microservice in JHipster v5.3.1?

Answer (score 1):

In v5, OAuth2 microservices require a database.  This change happened because OAuth2 microservice entities can now have relationships with the User, which means the user table is required.  A related issue with some discussion can be found here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7669

We're open to contributions but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to allow both behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

To run Gateway without database you have to manually make some changes and run `jhipster` again to regenerate it. But it's convenient to make these changes after every upgrade. Below are the changes to make:

Modify database options in .yo-rc.json as follows:

```
"databaseType": "no",
"devDatabaseType": "no",
"prodDatabaseType": "no",
```

Then run `jhipster`

Delete these files:

```
config/DatabaseConfiguration.java
config/audit/AuditEventConverter.java
domain/AbstractAuditingEntity.java
domain/PersistentAuditEvent.java
```

And delete `config/liquibase` folder and all related files.

Comment: and it is better to remove all the liquibase references from application(yml) and pom.xml